# Change SpriteNodes coordinates with User touch

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, draggable, sprite-kit

I'm currently programming a small game with `SpriteKit` in `Xcode` for the `iOS` platform. I wrote a code which adds some `SpriteNodes` on 2 different "lines", so half of the nodes are moving with the y-coordinate 100 and the others with y = 200, and they're all moving from the left side to the right which an infinity loop. Now I want that the user can touch on one `SpriteNode`, then moves his finger to another `SpriteNode`, but it has to be located on another line, then removes his finger and the `SpriteNode` with the `TOUCHBEGAN` should change its y-coordinate with the `TOUCHEND` Node. How can I accomplish this?

```
-(void)add
{
    SKSpriteNode *sprite2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"test1.png"];
    sprite2.position = CGPointMake(-40, self.frame.size.height / 2);
    sprite2.size = CGSizeMake(100, 32);

    SKSpriteNode *sprite3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"test.png"];
    sprite3.position = CGPointMake(-40, (self.frame.size.height / 2) + 90);
    sprite3.size = CGSizeMake(32, 100);

    [self addChild:sprite1];

    [self addChild:sprite2];

     SKAction *actionMove1 = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(400, (self.frame.size.height / 2) - 90) duration:12];
    SKAction *actionMove2 = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(200, (self.frame.size.height / 2)) duration:12];


    SKAction *actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    [sprite1 runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove1, actionMoveDone]]];
    [sprite2 runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove2, actionMoveDone]]];


}

- (void)updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:(CFTimeInterval)timeSinceLast
{
    self.lastSpawnTime += timeSinceLast;
    if (self.lastSpawnTime > 2)
    {
        self.lastSpawnTime = 0;
        [self add];

    }
}

- (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    CFTimeInterval timeSinceLast = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTime;
    self.lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
    if (timeSinceLast > 2)
    {
        timeSinceLast = 1.0 /60.0;
        self.lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
    }

    [self updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:timeSinceLast];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass SkSpriteNode:

- to detect TouchEvents you have to set "userInteractionEnabled" to "YES"
- to react on TouchEvents implement the touch method which fits for you needs:

> ```
> - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}
> - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}
> - (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}
> - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}
> ```

In this method you can change the coordinates of your sprite

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what to write inside this methods!

Answer (score 0):

add these function like that in your sksence

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

```
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if([node.name isEqualToString:@"plane"])
    {
        NSLog(@"_______touch ended");
        //x and y position of object at Scene
        NSLog(@"%f",node.position.x);
        NSLog(@"%f",node.position.y);
        NSLog(@"%@",node);
    }
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if([node.name isEqualToString:@"plane"])
    {
        NSLog(@"_______touch mobing");

    }
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
   SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if([node.name isEqualToString:@"plane"])
    {
                NSLog(@"______touch begin");
        //x and y position of object at Scene
        NSLog(@"%f",node.position.x);
        NSLog(@"%f",node.position.y);
        NSLog(@"%@",node);
    }
}
```